# PostgreSQL JDBC driver can't infer the SQL type when used with DBCP and JNDI loaded by Jetty context configuration

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jetty, jndi, jetty-9

I'm facing a very confusing situation and I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL as a pooled datasource managed by Jetty. DBCP2.1 is also used as the pool manager. The datasource is configured in a Jetty context config file similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="war">
        <Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/root.war
    </Set>
    <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
    <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>
    <Set name="configurationDiscovered">true</Set>


    <!-- Postgresql connection pool using DBCP2 -->
    <New id="ketabakds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>
            <Ref refid='wac'/>
        </Arg>
        <Arg>jdbc/dbpool</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.Driver</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pg_databse</Set>
                <Set name="username">pg_user</Set>
                <Set name="password">pg_pass</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>

</Configure>
```

datasource is then later retrieved in my code with something like this:

```
        DataSource source = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/dbpool");
```

This all works fine until I try to set anything on a prepared statement using the PGobject class. For example I have this code to pass on some JSON:

```
        PGobject jsonObject = new PGobject();
        jsonObject.setType(JSON_TYPE);
        jsonObject.setValue(json);

        statement = aConnection.prepareStatement(
                "insert into " +
                        tableName() +
                        " (data) values (?)"
        );

        statement.setObject(1, jsonObject);
        statement.executeUpdate();
```

here I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.postgresql.util.PGobject. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:1039) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:189) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:189) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
```

I even debugged into the PgPreparedStatement.java:1039, the very interesting point is that the passed on value (named x) is still of type PGobject but evaluating x instance of PGobject returns false.

I suspect the problem is that Jetty loads the PG's JDBC drivers twice. Once when loading context configuration and the second time when WAR application is loaded itself. Therefore there are two PGobject classes, even though they both have exact package names.

I'm not a jetty profi but is that possible? is there a solution for it so that I can use PGobject for passing values to prepared statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the reason of problem. As I suspected the PostgreSQL JDBC drivers were loaded two times once by Jetty as a result of context configuration and the second time inside the web application.

I solved the problem by removing the dependency from web application and leaving it to jetty to load the app. As my build tool is Gradle, this means I set the dependency of postgresql drivers for the web app to compileOnly.